# Create a List of Dictionaries using Comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, list-comprehension

I currently have a list of strings that I am trying to create each string item into a dictionary object and store it within a list.

In attempting to create this list of dictionaries, I repeatedly create one big dictionary instead of iterating through item by item.

My code:

`clothes_dict = [{clothes_list[i]: clothes_list[i + 1] for i in range(0, len(clothes_list), 2)}]`

The error (All items being merged into one dictionary):

````
clothes_dict = {list: 1} [{'name': 'Tom', 'age': 10}, {'name': 'Mark', 'age': 5}, {'name': 'Pam', 'age': 7}]
 0 = {dict: 2} {'name': 'Tom', 'age': 10}, {dict: 2} {'name': 'Mark', 'age': 5}, {'name': 'Pam', 'age': 7}```
````

Target Output (All Items being created into separate dictionaries within the single list):

````
clothes_dict = {list: 3} [{'name': 'Tom', 'age': 10}, {'name': 'Mark', 'age': 5}, {'name': 'Pam', 'age': 7}]
 0 = {dict: 2} {'name': 'Tom', 'age': 10}
 1 = {dict: 2} {'name': 'Mark', 'age': 5}
 2 = {dict: 2} {'name': 'Pam', 'age': 7}```
````

I am attempting to make each entry within the list a new dictionary in the same form as the target output image.

Comment: Images of your IDE are not useful here. If you want to increase your odds of getting useful help, here's what is needed: [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: [**PLEASE DO NOT POST TEXT AS IMAGES**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Copy and paste the text into your question and use the code formatting tool to format it correctly. Images are not searchable, and can not be interpreted by screen readers for those with visual impairments. Use the [edit] link to modify your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
clothes_dict = [{clothes_list[i]: clothes_list[i + 1]} for i in range(0, len(clothes_list), 2)]
```

You misplaced your closing right curly brace '}' in your list comprehension and placed it at the end which meant you was performing a dictionary comprehension as opposed to a list comprehension with each item being a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Your code creates a list with a single dictionary:

```
clothes_dict = [{clothes_list[i]: clothes_list[i + 1] for i in range(0,l en(clothes_list), 2)}]
```

If you (for some reason) want a list of dictionaries with single entries:

```
clothes_dict = [{clothes_list[i]: clothes_list[i + 1]} for i in range(0,l en(clothes_list), 2)]
```

However, it seems to me that this may be a bit of an XY problem - in what case is a list of single-entry dictionaries the required format? Why not use a list of tuples for example?